# Confusion about 'standardize' option of glmnet package in R

Tags: r, glmnet

I have a confusion about the `standardize` option of `glmnet` package in `R`. I get different coefficients when I standardize the covariates matrix and set `standardize=FALSE` vs. when I do not standardize the covariates matrix and set `standardize=TRUE`. I assumed they would be the same! These two are shown with an example by creating the following `ridge.mod1` and `ridge.mod2` models. I also created a model (`ridge.mod3`) that standardized the outcome (and the covariates matrix) and used the option `standardize=FALSE`. I was just checking if I needed to standardize the outcome too to get the same coefficients as in `ridge.mod1`.

```
set.seed(1)
y <- rnorm(30, 20, 10) 
x1 <- rnorm(30, 5, 2)
x2 <- x1 + rnorm(30, 0, 5)
cor(x1,x2)
x <- as.matrix(cbind(x1,x2))
z1 <- scale(x1)
z2 <- scale(x2)
z <- as.matrix(cbind(z1,z2))
y.scale <- scale(y)
n <- 30
# Fixing foldid for proper comparison
foldid=sample(rep(seq(5),length=n))
table(foldid)

library(glmnet)
cv.ridge.mod1 <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, nfolds = 5, foldid=foldid, standardize = TRUE)
ridge.mod1 <- glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, standardize = TRUE)
coef(ridge.mod1, s=cv.ridge.mod1$lambda.min)

> coef(ridge.mod1, s=cv.ridge.mod1$lambda.min)
3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       1
(Intercept) 2.082458e+01
x1          2.856136e-37
x2          4.334910e-38

cv.ridge.mod2 <- cv.glmnet(z, y, alpha = 0, nfolds = 5, foldid=foldid, standardize = FALSE)
ridge.mod2 <- glmnet(z, y, alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE)
coef(ridge.mod2, s=cv.ridge.mod2$lambda.min)

> coef(ridge.mod2, s=cv.ridge.mod2$lambda.min)
3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       1
(Intercept) 2.082458e+01
V1          4.391657e-37
V2          2.389751e-37

cv.ridge.mod3 <- cv.glmnet(z, y.scale, alpha = 0, nfolds = 5, foldid=foldid, standardize = FALSE)
ridge.mod3 <- glmnet(z, y.scale, alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE)
coef(ridge.mod3, s=cv.ridge.mod3$lambda.min)

> coef(ridge.mod3, s=cv.ridge.mod3$lambda.min)
3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                       1
(Intercept) 1.023487e-16
V1          4.752255e-38
V2          2.585973e-38
```

Could anyone please tell me what's going on there and if (or how) I can get the same coefficients as in `ridge.mod1` with prior standardization (in the data processing step) and then using `standardize=FALSE`?

**Update:** (what I tried based on the comments below)

So, I tried standardizing by SS/n instead of SS/(n-1). I tried by standardizing both y and x. Neither gave me coefficients equal to the de-standardized coefficients of model 1.

```
## Standadizing by sqrt(SS(X)/n) like glmnet instead of sqrt(SS(X)/(n-1)) which is done by the scale command
Xs <- apply(x, 2, function(m) (m - mean(m)) / sqrt(sum(m^2) / n))
Ys <- (y-mean(y)) / sqrt(sum(y^2) / n)

# Standadizing only X by sqrt(SS(X)/n)
cv.ridge.mod4 <- cv.glmnet(Xs, y, alpha = 0, nfolds = 5, foldid=foldid, standardize = FALSE)
ridge.mod4 <- glmnet(Xs, y, alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE)
coef(ridge.mod4, s=cv.ridge.mod4$lambda.min)

> coef(ridge.mod4, s=cv.ridge.mod4$lambda.min)[2]/sd(x1)
[1] 7.995171e-38
> coef(ridge.mod4, s=cv.ridge.mod4$lambda.min)[3]/sd(x2)
[1] 2.957854e-38

# Standadizing both Y and X by sqrt(SS(X)/n) but neither is centered
cv.ridge.mod6 <- cv.glmnet(Xs.noncentered, Ys.noncentered, alpha = 0, nfolds = 5, foldid=foldid, standardize = FALSE)
ridge.mod6 <- glmnet(Xs.noncentered, Ys.noncentered, alpha = 0, standardize = FALSE)
coef(ridge.mod6, s=cv.ridge.mod6$lambda.min)

> coef(ridge.mod6, s=cv.ridge.mod6$lambda.min)[2] / (sqrt(sum(x1^2) / n))
[1] 1.019023e-39
> coef(ridge.mod6, s=cv.ridge.mod6$lambda.min)[3] / (sqrt(sum(x2^2) / n))
[1] 9.189263e-40
```

What is it that still is wrong there?

Comment: definitively the outcome should also be standardized. The glmnet package also uses a specific formula for the standardization. Please check this [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/211390/228393) where people have discussed this other forums.

Comment: Hi, I read the thread. The highest voted answer there links a page which says, "If the variables are each standardized with the standard deviation (eg with scale()), this approach lead to the same model as the previous one." Which is not what I see even after standardization of the outcome and covariates (ridge.mod3).

Comment: So if you have gone through the documentation of [glmnet](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Glmnet_Vignette.pdf) you can see at page 8 that glmnet returns a de-standardized coefficient when `standardize=TRUE`. Hence to reproduce the results using your own standardization you have to first understand the exact standardization. Then once you ran the model you have to take the coefficient vector and reverse the transformation using the formula that they show in page 8 of the linked pdf.

Comment: In other words first `scale()` does not achieve the same as their standardization. Second the coefficient reported in `ridge.mod1` are already de-standardized hence if you have teh right formula you can transform the coefficients in  `ridge.mod3`, you have to de-standardize them.

Comment: @Diegolog I'm not sure what's going on. But I cannot reproduce the de-standardized coefficients of model 1 (please see my updated codes). I also figured out the R report linked to the thread that is in your first comment didn't use `standardize=FALSE` when they input the standardized data, which doesn't look right to me.

Comment: you are doing it wrong. To destandardize the coeficient notice that B_std=B* sx/sy. See the posted answer for details.

Comment: if the answer works to satisfaction please mark it as accepted.

Comment: My bad! You mentioned it before that the y is also standardized. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tweaked your code so that I can work with a more sensible problem. In order to reproduce the coefficients changing the `standardize=TRUE` and `standardize=FALSE` options you need to first standardize the variables with the (1/N) variance estimator formula. For this example I also centered the variables to get rid of the constant. I focus only on the coefficients of the variables. After that you have to notice that  [image: formula] hence you have to invert that formula to get the de-standardized coefficients. I do that in the following code.

```
set.seed(1)

x1 <- rnorm(300, 5, 2)
x2 <- x1 + rnorm(300, 0, 5)
x3 <- rnorm(300, 6, 5)
e= rnorm(300, 0, 1)
y <- 0.3*x1+3.5*x2+x3+e

x <- as.matrix(cbind(x1,x2,x3))


sdN=function(x){
sigma=sqrt( (1/length(x)) * sum((x-mean(x))^2))
return(sigma)
}

n=300
foldid=sample(rep(seq(5),length=n))

g1=(x1-mean(x1))/sdN(x1)
g2=(x2-mean(x2))/sdN(x2)
g3=(x3-mean(x3))/sdN(x3)
gy=(y-mean(y))/sdN(y)
equis <- as.matrix(cbind(g1,g2,g3))



library(glmnet)
cv.ridge.mod1 <- cv.glmnet(x, y, alpha = 0, nfolds = 5, foldid=foldid,standardize = TRUE)
coef(cv.ridge.mod1, s=cv.ridge.mod1$lambda.min)


cv.ridge.mod2 <- cv.glmnet(equis, gy, alpha = 0, nfolds = 5, foldid=foldid, standardize = FALSE, intercept=FALSE)
beta=coef(cv.ridge.mod2, s=cv.ridge.mod2$lambda.min)


beta[2]*sdN(y)/sdN(x1)
beta[3]*sdN(y)/sdN(x2)
beta[4]*sdN(y)/sdN(x3)

coef(cv.ridge.mod1, s=cv.ridge.mod1$lambda.min)
```

this yields the results:

```
> beta[2]*sdN(y)/sdN(x1)
[1] 0.5984356
> beta[3]*sdN(y)/sdN(x2)
[1] 3.166033
> beta[4]*sdN(y)/sdN(x3)
[1] 0.9145646
> 
> coef(cv.ridge.mod1, s=cv.ridge.mod1$lambda.min)
4 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                    1
(Intercept) 0.5951423
x1          0.5984356
x2          3.1660328
x3          0.9145646
```

As you can see the coefficients are the same at 4 decimals. So I hope this answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, can you provide code to re-create the intercept as well? I am not sure how to do that...